# How to prevent child's element from exceeding it's parent element's fixed width?

Tags: html, css

I want to set a fixed width to a parent element and I want to put long text in it. but when text's length get bigger than it's parent 's width, it just exceeds it's parent's width, not to move to the next row.

So what i want to do is to make a flexible box that keeps it's context in its fixed width length ( of course the height of the box can change depending on the number of rows. )

Here is a simple code.

```
<style type="text/css">
.wrap {position:relative; width:500px; border:1px solid red;}
.child {width:50%; padding:5px;  border:1px solid blue;}
</style>

<div class="wrap">
<div class="child">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Comment: What you need is the `word-wrap` css attribute. Set it to `break-word` to let it wrap to the next line.

Comment: Thank you ! Can I also ask what should I do If i want to do this on block levels?
like I have this parent with value of display:flex and width :500px; and if it has three child blocks with width:50%, then it exceeds it's parent's domain, if you want to keep all child element in its parent, what can I do?